# Hibernate error when using a custom id generator with a suffix

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jhipster, liquibase

I am trying to create a custom id for my entity, but when i am trying to do it, i am getting an error.

Here is my code for the entity (part)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Notifications implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator = "seq_notifications")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "seq_notifications",
        strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.domain.PKeys.NotficationID")
    private String id;
```

here is the generator class code

```
public class NotficationID  extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "dateFormat";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%tY-%tm";

    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%05d";

    public static final String DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_PARAMETER = "dateNumberSeparator";
    public static final String DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT = "_";

    private String format;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
                                 Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return String.format(format, LocalDate.now(), super.generate(session, object));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
                          ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);

        String dateFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(DATE_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT).replace("%", "%1");
        String numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT).replace("%", "%2");
        String dateNumberSeparator = ConfigurationHelper.getString(DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_PARAMETER, params, DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT);
        this.format = dateFormat+dateNumberSeparator+numberFormat;
    }
}
```

and i'm getting this error when i try to insert a value

```
2020-06-25 09:56:14.718 DEBUG 15572 --- [  XNIO-1 task-4] c.m.m.web.rest.NotificationsResource     : REST request to save Notifications : Notifications{id=null, notificationType='null', notificationDate='null', message='null'}
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from seq_notifications for update
2020-06-25 09:56:14.744 ERROR 15572 --- [  XNIO-1 task-4] o.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure   : could not read a hi value

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'relationships.seq_notifications' doesn't exist
```

```
2020-06-25 09:56:14.746  WARN 15572 --- [  XNIO-1 task-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2020-06-25 09:56:14.746 ERROR 15572 --- [  XNIO-1 task-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'relationships.seq_notifications' doesn't exist
2020-06-25 09:56:14.753 ERROR 15572 --- [  XNIO-1 task-4] c.m.m.web.rest.NotificationsResource     : Exception in createNotifications() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work' and exception = 'error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work'
```

**Note that i am using jhipster**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when using a sequence generator, a table should be created that holds the next identifier. In your case case, it would be called seq_notifications, and would contain one column (next_val). Can you check if it exists in your database? Also do you have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in your application.properties ? Actually can you share your application.properties?

Comment: There is no such table as seq_notifications, if i remove generic generator and change the type to long, then it will generate the id without giving any errors,

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= is set to none, im getting an error if i change it to update...

Comment: The error is because seq_notifications table does not exist then. For the generator to work, this table must exist, to hold the next_val values. Which error do you get when you change it to update? You can also try droping the table and let spring recreate it again?

Comment: already tried dropping, can you please tell me the format of the seq_ table, 
i followed a tutorial, in that they do not create a seperate table.. :(

Comment: that is because it should be created automatically, maybe you should update the question with your update error. You can try creating one manually, it contains only one column: next_val  type bigint(20).  It should have already a value there, start with 1 ,since it is the next value.

Comment: I am also using liquibase, is it something i should configure there..??

Comment: my table name is userdetails and Entity class name is UserDetails. Could you please suggest me what is my generator. and my PK name is id

Answer (score 1):

i guess the problem was the table, I created a table and everything was fine, Thanks @Henrique, you were right,

I created a table with the name 'seq' but the data type was varchar(255) because my @Id is a String